# Using a Binary Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node_{
    int val;
    struct node_ *left;
    struct node_ *right;
}node;

node* insert(node* root,int val);
void inorder(node* root);
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int item;
    node* root = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        item = rand()%15;
        insert(root,item); 
    }

    inorder(root);

    return 0;    
}

node* insert(node* root,int val)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(root!= NULL)
        {
            (root)->val = val;
            (root)->left = NULL;
            (root)->right = NULL;
        }
        else 
            printf("%d not inserted. No memory available.\n",val);
    }
    else
    {
        if(val < (root)->val)
        {
            insert((root->left),val);
        }

        if(val>root->val)
        {
            insert(((root)->right),val);
        }
    }
}

void inorder(node* root)
{
    printf("%p",root);
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%3d",root->val);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a binary tree and print out the values in order. However when I run this code the printf of the address prints out nil obviously meaning that my tree is empty so the printf and recursion below does not run. I cannot figure out where I went wrong, any suggestions or answers would be appreciated because I can't figure out why the root would be null after calling all of those inserts in main.

Comment: is the failed allocation being set off? (root) makes no sense and may cause problems change to just root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `root` as a parameter to `insert()` (which says it is going to return something but doesn't). Inside `insert` you `malloc` your node and assign it to the local variable `root`. Nothing you ever do makes it out of the `insert` function.

Try returning something from `insert`, or using a global `root`.

As @JoshuaByer hints in the comments below, another approach is to make your `insert` method "pass by reference" so it can effectively modify what was passed to it.

```
void insert(node** rootp,int val)
{
    if(*rootp == NULL)
    {
        *rootp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    }
    /* and so on */
```

If you don't understand what this is saying, google "Pass by reference in C" and I'm positive you'll get some good information.

Comment: Root is not a local variable it is passed in as a pointer to the function

Comment: @JoshuaByer Ok, it's a parameter. How do the semantics differ from a local variable? It doesn't magically become pass by reference

Comment: Very good the problem he wants to pass by reference.. adjust answer accordingly

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the double pointer and passing by reference? I know how to do it that way but if i wanted to just use the single pointer how would it be done.

Comment: Actually I got it working by adding the return statement and in main having root = insert however only the first node is being created and printed out

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` after declaring and initializing root (`node* root = NULL;`) you're never assigning it. In order to fix you should probably change the lin `insert(root,item);` to `root = insert(root,item);`.

Also note that although `insert` is defined as returning `node *` it does not return any value.

Comment: in the insert it gets assigned if it is null

Comment: This assignment is meaningless and is only effective in the scope of `insert()`. In order to change a value of a pointer you should pass its address (i.e. `&root` of type `node**`) and then change it by referring to `*ppRoot`